# Matrix Logarithm for cvx package of optimization

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, matlab, entropy, semidefinite-programming

I have a convex optimization problem with the Hermitian semi-definite matrix variable. The problem is in fact a matrix entropy maximization with some other constraints which I don't mention for simplicity.

$$\min_{N} \quad Tr\{N \ln(N/q_0)\} + Tr\{(\rho - N) \ln(\frac{\rho - N}{1 - q_0})\}$$
where $0 \leq q_0 \leq 1$ and $\rho$  (a Hermitian semi-definite matrix) are the
given parameters of optimization. And $N$ is also a Hermitian semi-definite matrix which is variable of optimization. Note that the $ln(X)$ is the matrix logarithm which is different from the element-wise logarithm applied to matrices. So matlab has a built-in function $logm()$ which calculates this. But I would like to use the optimization package cvx and it apparently does not support this logm function:

```
cvx_begin
    variable N(2,2) hermitian semidefinite
    minimize(-trace(rho *logm(rho)) + trace(N*logm(N./q0)) +  trace((rho - N)*logm((rho - N)./(1 - q0))))
```

gives the following error

```
Error using logm (line 33)
Expected input to be one of these types:

double, single

Instead its type was cvx.
```

I appreciate any help on how to solve this optimization problem. I am new to optimization and do not know much about this. So any help or suggestion is great. I am also not obsessed with CVX in case you had a solution in another platform. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install CVXQUAD https://github.com/hfawzi/cvxquad . Then use its quantum_entr function. There is no need to install CVXQUAD’s exponential.m replacement.

Also see the discussion of matrix log related functions in CVXQUAD at the end of CVXQUAD: How to use CVXQUAD's Pade Approximant instead of CVX's unreliable Successive Approximation for GP mode, log, exp, entr, rel_entr, kl_div, log_det, det_rootn, exponential cone. CVXQUAD's Quantum (Matrix) Entropy & Matrix Log related functions .

The reference https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.00812 describes the matrix logarithm approximation used by CVXQUAD to convert `quantum_entr` into a set of Linear Matrix Inequalities, which can then be solved by SDP solvers such as Mosek, SeDuMi, or SDPT3.

Comment: Thank you so much @Mark . I was struggling with this for some time and didnt expect there would be a library that implemented these matrix exponential functions for cvx. I tested and it works perfectly.